# docker-machine looks for files in the wrong path

Tags: docker-machine

I was instructed to uninstall docker-machine as a snap and reinstall it directly from the source. Problem is that when I run `docker-machine version` it throws `bash: /snap/bin/docker-machine: No such file or directory` ... meaning new installation of docker machine still points to the old path not to new one.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be an obsolete bash cache.

As mentioned in the [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables) you can rehash your command:

```
hash docker-machine
```

clear bash cache just for your command:

```
hash -d docker-machine
```

or totally clear all the bash cache:

```
hash -r
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while that you posted this question, but I answer for future references.

*This is not an actual solution but a hack maybe.*

You need to create a link between the actual path to the newly installed `docker-machine` and the wrong path that `docker-machine` is looking for installation:

```
$ sudo ln /usr/local/bin/docker-machine /snap/bin/docker-machine
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.16.0, build 702c267f
```